# Using VB Excel Importing data text with open window

Tags: vba, excel

Hi i very new to VB programming in Excel. I've been assigned a job to create a macro to merge two external txt file. That's a problem that the location of this two files might be located differently in client side.

Here is the code that i am using.
Is there anyway i can import data text with open window? And After i set the active cell to the last row, i wish to import another data text again and adjust the column width. Appreciate a lot for any suggestion.

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant, wb As Workbook
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
        If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fNameAndPath)

        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
'
'do stuff
'
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Change this code:

```
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
```

to this code:

```
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text Files (*.TXT), *.TXT", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
```

Then instead of using `Workbook.Open`, use `Workbook.OpenText`.
To get the correct syntax, record macro and try opening the file in excel.
Then edit the macro code based on what you need.